# extract the number from a string

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

I am using `preg_match()` to extract a number from a string. 
Example string is: `advent_id ----------- 3163 (1 row)`, I need to extract the number followed by the hyphens and not the number of rows. What is the correct way of writing a regex for it?
I tried `preg_match('/^advent_id\s------------\s(.*)\s\(/', $cn, $matches);` where `$cn` has that source string, but it did not work. Note that the number could have any number of digits.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? Error? Wrong result?

Comment: Your regex is a bit strange, in that on the one hand it requires a very specific format -- exact number of hyphens, etc. -- while on the other it's very loose -- using `\s` instead of a space, using `.*` instead of `\d+`, etc.

Comment: @m.buettner it did not match anything. Well, '/\d+/' worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the first integer in the row.

```
$x = 'advent_id ----------- 3163 (1 row)';
preg_match('/\d+/', $x, $m);
echo "$m[0]\n";
```

Produces:

```
3163
```

**edit**

as you can see, the default behaviour of `preg_match()` is to match the first occurrence, then stop. It's different of `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
$s = 'advent_id ----------- 3163 (1 row)';
preg_match('~-+ (\d+)~', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

#### will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ----------- 3163
    [1] => 3163
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Your main problem was your `.*` was matching any character so you had to make your regular expression complicated to make sure it only was grabbing numbers. By changing that part to `[0-9]*` it will only match numbers and will make your regex simpler.

```
$cn = 'advent_id ----------- 3163 (1 row)';
preg_match('/^advent_id -* ([0-9]*)/', $cn, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$string = "advent_id ----------- 3163 (1 row)" ;
$matches = array();
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
print($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
 3163
```