# How can I find a number in a string with PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

How can I find a number in a string with PHP?
for example :

```
<?
    $a="Cl4";
?>
```

i have a string like this 'Cl4' . i wanna if there is a number like '4' in the string give me this number but if there is not a number in the string give me 1 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

This may help.

Comment: @Nile :) Almost at the same time

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    function get_number($input) {
        $input = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);

        return $input == '' ? '1' : $input;
    }

    echo get_number('Cl4');

?>
```

Comment: i have another question :D . i wanna solve an equation with PHP . for example :' a 2 = b 3 ' .
i wanna find slowest integer value for a , b . can you help me ?

Comment: @hassanzanjani, post this as another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'CI4';
preg_match("/(\d)/",$str,$matches);
echo isset($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : 1;

$str = 'CIA';
preg_match("/(\d)/",$str,$matches);
echo isset($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "str3ng";
$number = (preg_match("/(\d)/", $input, $matches) ? $matches[0]) : 1; // 3

$input = "str1ng2";
$number = (preg_match_all("/(\d)/", $input, $matches) ? implode($matches) : 1; // 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **simple** function which will extract number from your your string and if number not found it will return 1

```
<?php

function parse_number($string) {
    preg_match("/[0-9]/",$string,$matches);
    return isset($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : 1;
}

$str = 'CI4';
echo parse_number($str);//Output : 4

$str = 'ABCD';
echo parse_number($str); //Output : 1
?>
```