# php - regex - how to extract a number with decimal (dot and comma) from a string (e.g. 1,120.01)?

Tags: php, regex

how to extract a number with decimal (dot and comma) from a string (e.g. 1,120.01) ?
 I have a regex but doesn't seem to play well with commas

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $s, $matches);
```

Answer (score 30):

### The correct regex for matching numbers with commas and decimals is as follows (The first two will validate that the number is correctly formatted):

---

### decimal optional (two decimal places)

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YSCk5jd2XjmtM6U_)**

**Explained:**

```
number (decimal optional)

^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$

Options: case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[+-]?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   The character “+” «+»
   The character “-” «-»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,3}»
   Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»
Match the regular expression below «(?:,?[0-9]{3})*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the character “,” literally «,?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
      Exactly 3 times «{3}»
Match the regular expression below «(?:\.[0-9]{2})?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

***Will Match:***

```
1,432.01
456.56
654,246.43
432
321,543
```

***Will not Match***

```
454325234.31
324,123.432
,,,312,.32
123,.23
```

---

### decimal mandatory (two decimal places)

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0B--SOn967897QaW)**

**Explained:**

```
number (decimal required)

^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$

Options: case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[+-]?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   The character “+” «+»
   The character “-” «-»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{1,3}»
   Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»
Match the regular expression below «(?:,?[0-9]{3})*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the character “,” literally «,?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
      Exactly 3 times «{3}»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

***Will Match:***

```
1,432.01
456.56
654,246.43
324.75
```

***Will Not Match:***

```
1,43,2.01
456,
654,246
324.7523
```

---

### Matches Numbers separated by commas or decimals indiscriminately:

```
^(\d+(.|,))+(\d)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mNDakHGxuFq4wjWT)**

**Explained:**

```
    Matches Numbers Separated by , or .

^(\d+(.|,))+(\d)+$

Options: case insensitive

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+(.|,))+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «+»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.|,)»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «.»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «,»
         Match the character “,” literally «,»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\d)+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «+»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d»
```

***Will Match:***

```
1,32.543,2
5456.35,3.2,6.1
2,7
1.6
```

***Will Not Match:***

```
1,.2 // two ., side by side
1234,12345.5467. // ends in a .
,125 // begins in a ,
,.234 // begins in a , and two symbols side by side
123,.1245. // ends in a . and two symbols side by side
```

---

***Note:** wrap either in a group and then just pull the group, let me know if you need more specifics.*

***Description:** This type of RegEx works with any language really (PHP, Python, C, C++, C#, JavaScript, jQuery, etc).  These Regular Expressions are good for currency mainly.*

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex: -

```
/((?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/
```

**Explanation: -**

```
/(
    (?:[0-9]+,)*   # Match 1 or more repetition of digit followed by a `comma`. 
                   # Zero or more repetition of the above pattern.
    [0-9]+         # Match one or more digits before `.`
    (?:            # A non-capturing group
        \.         # A dot
        [0-9]+     # Digits after `.`
    )?             # Make the fractional part optional.
 )/
```

Comment: and what about `44.336.455,33`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ.. Didn't consider that thing, as not specified. That will require some modification.

Comment: @RohitJain I didn't downvote, but I believe your regex would accept `192,192,1,.2`. You're always going to have a comma before the decimal.

Comment: @RohitJain Now you couldn't accept a number that doesn't include commas.

Comment: @Michael.. Duh. Nice catch. :) Edited.

Comment: @Anirudha here you go : `((?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*(?:\.[0-9]+)*(?:,)?)`

- not only will it catch "44.336.455,33," but it will even get "44.336.455,33.3.3.3.3,3"

Answer (score 4):

Add the comma to the range that can be in front of the dot:

```
/([0-9,]+\.[0-9]+)/
#     ^ Comma
```

And this regex:

```
/((?:\d,?)+\d\.[0-9]*)/
```

Will only match

```
1,067120.01
121,34,120.01
```

But not

```
,,,.01
,,1,.01
12,,,.01

# /(
#   (?:\d,?) Matches a Digit followed by a optional comma
#   +        And at least one or more of the previous
#   \d       Followed by a digit (To prevent it from matching `1234,.123`)
#   \.?      Followed by a (optional) dot
#            in case a fraction is mandatory, remove the `?` in the previous section.
#   [0-9]*   Followed by any number of digits  -->  fraction? replace the `*` with a `+`
# )/
```

Comment: This would also match `,,,,,,,,,,,.90213`

Comment: @Michael: True, Working on it.

Comment: and what about `3243,424,42,423`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Good point. (Or rather, lack thereof :P) Editing.

Comment: I get (
    [0] => 443.00
    [1] => 443.00
) on $US 44,443.00

Comment: @user1963938: what's your input?

Comment: currency IDs along with numbers in different formats such 123  ; 123.00 ;   1,992.00 ; 293,993.00  . The point is to get only the numbers / values without currency IDs or symbols .

Comment: @user1963938: My latest edit (`/((?:\d,?)+\d\.[0-9]*)/`) does match the full number, like `44,443.00` on `$US 44,443.00`.

Answer (score 0):

The locale-aware float (%f) might be used with sscanf.

```
$result = sscanf($s, '%f')
```

That doesn't split the parts into an array though. It simply parses a float.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

A regex approach:

```
/([0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
preg_match('/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?/', $s, $matches);
```

Comment: How about `2131,.13` and `123,123,1234`?

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry I was too focused on his example, I'll edit it if I have a correct regex or delete it if not, thans @Cerbrus

Comment: That also matches `,,,.01`, `2131,.13` and `123,123.123,123.123`, for example.

Comment: Now I guess this should catch only valid numbers like 1,234.56

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great working regex. This accepts numbers with commas and decimals.

```
/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/
```