# PHP - How to find numbers and bold that numbers in a string

Tags: php, string, numbers

How I can make all the numbers in a string bold?

For example:
`$st_nu = "Today123"` would become `Today<b>123</b>`.

Comment: Bold where? Web page? Console? Report file? Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Wrap it in a `<strong>` tag.

Comment: I already used 

$str_replace = str_replace(range(0,9),"<strong>".range(0,9)."</strong>", $st_nu);

But its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to bolden only numbers.

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $st_nu);
```

What this does is matches any number 1 or more characters long, then surrounds it with the `<b>` tag (bold).

Using your example, you'd get back the following:

> Today**123**

Comment: Hi bro, if I want to make the word Today also to bold ,then what I have to do?

Comment: You'd have to add Today as an option in your regular expression: `preg_replace('/(\d+|(Today)+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $st_nu);`

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string) answer to remove the numbers from the string. Then, if you want to output it to HTML, you can wrap it in a `<b>` tag, or preferably use CSS to style it.

So you can do

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $st_nu, $matches);
```

Edit: I misunderstood your question a little. Here's a way to do it. If you have more than one number, you can loop through the matches array.

```
foreach ($matches as $res) {
    $replaceStr = "<b>" . $res . "</b>";
    str_replace($res, $replaceStr, $st_nu);
}
```

Comment: But I have a string like   $srctitle = "Environment and Pollution , Volume 1, Issue 1, pages 536-555";   so it should display the numbers in that string in bold, using your example its showing array.