# How to trim string of all characters except integers in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a collection of possible sizes that I would like to trim, see as follows:

> quantity_c_size_12_chain
>
> quantity_c_size_12
>
> quantity_size_12_chain
>
> quantity_size_12
>
> quantity_c_size_12_con_c
>
> quantity_c_size_12_con_b

I would like to trim the string of all characters except the integer (in this example, 12)

At the moment I have this:

```
$size = preg_replace('#\d.*$#', '', $_GET['size']);
```

Unfortunately this does just the opposite of what I need, it strips the integer from the string and retains the alpha characters i.e. quantity_size_

Can anybody tell me what I need to do to remove everything except the integer?

Thanks,

Comment: Use `preg_match()` instead ?

Comment: Is it always string and number seperate with _ 
(underscore) symbol then try explode() with _ and then find is_numeric () then take it out, And you can use easly @dikesh answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$size = preg_replace("/\D+/", '', $_GET['size']);
```

where `\D` are non-digits, as opposed to `\d`

Answer (score 1):

Try below: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

```
$str = 'quantity_size_12_chain';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'quantity_c_size_12_chain';
$new_str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$str);
```

Comment: Is it so difficult to understand?

Comment: Probably not, but in order to be a quality answer it should be at least minimally explained.