# How to Use FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

Tags: php, html

I use this line of code

```
echo number_format  ($debit_sum_500to791,2);
```

Then it echo me the value if its Plus or minus

I want to filter the value of PLUS or Minus  and get only the  numbers.

example: `if its -10 i need only 10`

So i use  this way

```
echo (number_format  ($debit_sum_500to791,2),FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

but it does not working, come empty blank page

I think im not doing it right, so can any one help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`abs`](http://php.net/abs)

Any negative or positive value will become positive.

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

or

```
$str= '-10';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0]; // 10
```

For more :- [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: the original  value i get -0.02, after the filter -002, but still with  the minus sign. i am after result is  0.02

Answer (score 1):

Try with php abs() function
ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php