# How to compare numbers inside a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string:

HELLO WORLD by Adam Smith published 1920 born 1890;

How I can check that year after 'born' 1890 not greater then year after published 1920?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression to extract the digits from the letters and compare:

```
$str="HELLO WORLD by Adam Smith published 1920 born 1890";
$patt="/\d{4}/";
$res=preg_match_all($patt,$str,$matches);
if($matches[0] > $matches[1]){
    echo 'Year of birth is before year of publishing';
}else{
    echo 'Looks like time travelling: published before even born ...';
}
```

$matches holds:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1920
                [1] => 1890
            )
    )

The preg_match_all function extracts all 4 digit character chain and lays that into the array $matches.
But you have to be sure, that the sentence has no other year (or 4 digit stings) and that the published date is the first and birth date second argument in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To compare numbers with numbers, check:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I think he asked how to extract those number from the string instead of actually comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would do the trick to extract the 2 numbers from a string and then you compare the 2 numbers. See [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)