# Return numeric value from string

Tags: php, string, numbers, integer, preg-match

Title is pretty much self explanatory but just to clarify.

I want to fetch the numeric value out of string witch is not necessarily contains only numeric values.

Now I can do that with `preg_match` but I was wondering if there is an internal php command that can do it in a cleaner way.

so... just to clarify with example:

```
$myString = 'qazwsxedc15rfvtgbyhnujmikolp';
$myString = fetchNumber($myString); //Expecting to get $myString=15;
```

Comment: Maybe this is a good solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string/12582416#12582416

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's an out of the box function that can fetch numbers from a string.
There are certain conventions such as strings beginning with numbers can be type casted to integers.

Anyway, preg_match might not be optimal. Consider using `preg_replace`

```
function fetchNumber($string)
{
  $string = preg_replace('#[^\d]*#', '', $string);
  return (int)$string;
}

$myString = 'qazwsxedc15rfvtgbyhnujmikolp';
$myString = fetchNumber($myString); //Expecting to get $myString=15;

var_dump($myString);
```

You do lose the "dot" that can signal floats, but your scenario excluded this possibility as far as I noticed.

[Live Example on sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b8d77ce160ca8e3bc5594a44d94971805b3199c)

Comment: Thanks bro ! I just find out that it IS possible to get it right of the box with intval(filter_var($matches[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); Working Perfectly !!!

Comment: `[^\d]` is the same as `\D`.  `*` doesn't make a lot of sense -- why match a zero with string and replace it with an empty string.  I think it should be `/\D+/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$str = 'qazwsxedc15rfvtgbyhnujmikolp';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```