# How to get a number out of a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have following string

```
Casas (3)
```

I want to get the number three out of it .

in Jquery I am using this regex

```
regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
```

But i dont know how to do that in PHP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "Casas (3)";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is the difference to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6278312/3933332) besides the string? If answer = none -> this would be a dupe

Comment: yeah..i dint check it..as there are lot of preg match question answers available...

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
<?php 
$text = 'Casas (3)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];

?>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match with your regular expression

```
$f = 'Casas (3)';
preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $f, $fr)
echo $fr[1];
```