# PHP - cut everything before and after price in a string

Tags: php, regex

I got strings like these:

```
Test 120,00 Euro yaddayadda
200 € with 18 months of blablabla
3.000,65 € something . And here s something more with 0815. And more.
1 Euro
Last item for 5.234.789,00 Euro.
```

and I want to get rid of everything except the price.
So with these examples it should be

```
120,00
200
3.000,65
1
5.234.789,00
```

I already got

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $string);
```

but that ain't enough. It turns

```
3.000,65 € something . And here s something more with 0815. And more.
```

into

```
3.000,65.0815..
```

Close...but still not enough.

Thx!

Comment: Instead of trying to replace, use `preg_match_all` to extract what you want.

Comment: See [**Extract numbers from a string**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6278312/1407478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^\D*(\b\d+([,.]\d+)*\b).*$/m', '$1', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB4nF5/1)

This regex:

```
\D*           # matches all non-digits from start
\b            # word boundary
\d+([,.]\d+)* # matches your floating point number in each line
(...)         # groups these numbers
.*$           # match rest of the line
```

And replacement is `$1` which is captured number.

Comment: I think an explanation for OP and further readers would be helpful what the regex exactly does

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. However that's one hell of a preg_replace...do you got some kind of explanation for Future Me? :)

Comment: Yes I've just added an explanation and besides my demo link also has a great explanation of this regex.

Comment: And the `/m` turns on multiline mode.