# extracting part of a string in php

Tags: php

These are my possible strings.

```
$str = 'price-100-500';
$str = 'price-200-600';
```

I want two variables from the string. 
From first string, I want

```
$val1 = 100;
$val2 = 500;
```

From second string, I want

```
$val1 = 200;
$val2 = 600;
```

Please, how can I get?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried in order to achieve this

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6278296/3933332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP `explode` function. See my codes as below:

```
$str = 'price-100-500';
$arr = explode('-',$str);
$val1 = $arr[1];
$val2 = $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do in simple way:

```
$str = 'price-100-500';
list($val1, $val2) = explode('-', str_replace('price-', '', $str));
echo '<br>val1 : '.$val1;
echo '<br>val2 : '.$val2;
```

Output

```
val1 : 100
val2 : 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$str = 'price-100-500';
$exploded=explode("-",$str);
echo $exploded[1];//will echo 100
echo $exploded[2];//will echo 500
```

Similarly you can explode any string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are willing to have this from several similar $str, and if you have them as an array, you can use the following code block to get them all as array output --

```
foreach($strings as $string){
    $arr = explode('-',$string);
    $result[$string]['val1'] = $arr[1];
    $result[$string]['val2'] = $arr[2];
}

print_r($result);
```

This will give you an output like

```
Array
(
    [price-100-500] => Array
        (
            [val1] => 100
            [val2] => 500
        )

    [price-200-600] => Array
        (
            [val1] => 200
            [val2] => 600
        )

)
```

For better and exact answer you should provide better explanation of your problem. Hope for the best.

Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

For your first example:

```
 <?php

        $str = 'price-100-500';
        $arrayStr=explode("-",$str);
        $val1 = $arrayStr[1];
        $val2 = $arrayStr[2];

    ?>
```

If u wan't a function you can use this:

```
<?php

    $str = 'price-100-500';
    $array = getMyVar($str);
    echo $array[0];
    echo $array[1];


    function getMyVar($str){
        $arrayStr=explode("-",$str);
        $val1 = $arrayStr[1];
        $val2 = $arrayStr[2];

        return array($val1,$val2);
    }

?>
```