# Using PHP to find the number inside {{2461245}}

Tags: php

What is the best way to extract the number in the following string:

```
"This is a test string {2461245} and I need to extract the number"
```

Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

This should help you :

```
$myText = 'This is a test string {2461245} and I need to extract the number';
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$myText);
```

What you are saying there is : I want to replace everything which is not a number in the myText variable by "", which means everything which will stay in the end is your number.

Comment: Actually I realized this won't work in all situations because the string that is being scanned may sometimes include other numbers.  And what I really need is to find the number that I'm now putting inside an HTML comment, like this: <!--2461245-->.  Thank you.