# PHP: Store dynamically generated text field values in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one array contains the result set from dynamically generated text box values.

In the below example I created three dynamically generated rows and each row contains 6 text field. For differentiate each row name i added the row id as the last word of name. Example `ClaimExecutionCountry1` means `ClaimExecutionCountry` as the name and `1` is the row id.

```
Array
(
[0] => ClaimExecutionCountry1=10
[1] => activitystartdate1=05-27-2016
[2] => activityenddate1=06-24-2016
[3] => CLCode1=CLC1
[4] => SCSCode1=SCS1
[5] => fileName1=calc2.png
[6] => ClaimExecutionCountry2=53
[7] => activitystartdate2=05-27-2016
[8] => activityenddate2=05-28-2016
[9] => CLCode2=
[10] => SCSCode2=
[11] => fileName2=gh.png
[12] => ClaimExecutionCountry3=82
[13] => activitystartdate3=05-26-2016
[14] => activityenddate3=07-28-2016
[15] => CLCode3=
[16] => SCSCode3=SCS5
[17] => fileName3=preview1.png
)
```

I am facing one issue for storing these values in Database. In my database structure is below

```
Id  |   ClaimExecutionCountry  |   activitystartdate  |  activityenddate  | CLCode  | SCSCode  |  fileName
```

I need to store after `=` symbol values in this table.

after insert the table, the result would be

```
 Id  |   ClaimExecutionCountry  |   activitystartdate  |  activityenddate  | CLCode  | SCSCode  |  fileName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |         10               |      05-27-2016      |     06-24-2016    |   CLC1  |  SCS1    |  calc2.png  
 2   |         53               |      05-27-2016      |     05-28-2016    |   null  |  null    |  gh.png   
 3   |         82               |      05-26-2016      |     07-28-2016    |   null  |  SCS5    |  preview1.png
```

So Anyone please help me to store the array values in database using above format. I think you understood my problem. I am using PHP,codignator and MySql as database. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tries so far??

Comment: I tried many options like explode the results in an array and based on count(in the example count is 3) i put for loop. In the loop i tried to to separate each row. but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try code below:

```
$_array=Array(
        [0] => ClaimExecutionCountry1=10
        [1] => activitystartdate1=05-27-2016
        [2] => activityenddate1=06-24-2016
        [3] => CLCode1=CLC1
        [4] => SCSCode1=SCS1
        [5] => fileName1=calc2.png
        [6] => ClaimExecutionCountry2=53
        [7] => activitystartdate2=05-27-2016
        [8] => activityenddate2=05-28-2016
        [9] => CLCode2=
        [10] => SCSCode2=
        [11] => fileName2=gh.png
        [12] => ClaimExecutionCountry3=82
        [13] => activitystartdate3=05-26-2016
        [14] => activityenddate3=07-28-2016
        [15] => CLCode3=
        [16] => SCSCode3=SCS5
        [17] => fileName3=preview1.png
        )
        foreach($_array as $val){
            $a = explode("=",$val);
            $field = $a[0];
            $ans=$a[1];
            $matches = array();
            if (preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $field, $matches)) {

                $rowNum=$matches[1];
            }
            $fieldName = str_replace($rowNum,"",$field);
            /*Now you have number of row , $fieldName , $rowNum and $ans so we can execute SQl statement inside forEach*/
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you sure that it work #(\d+)$# ? I mean, # after $?

Comment: @degr , Yes you can refer link below for more.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Array
(
[0] => ClaimExecutionCountry1=10
[1] => activitystartdate1=05-27-2016
[2] => activityenddate1=06-24-2016
[3] => CLCode1=CLC1
[4] => SCSCode1=SCS1
[5] => fileName1=calc2.png
[6] => ClaimExecutionCountry2=53
[7] => activitystartdate2=05-27-2016
[8] => activityenddate2=05-28-2016
[9] => CLCode2=
[10] => SCSCode2=
[11] => fileName2=gh.png
[12] => ClaimExecutionCountry3=82
[13] => activitystartdate3=05-26-2016
[14] => activityenddate3=07-28-2016
[15] => CLCode3=
[16] => SCSCode3=SCS5
[17] => fileName3=preview1.png
)
Take the count of array------
$cnt = count($a);

<!--now loop it and explode it to get the values after = -->
for($i=0;$i<=$cnt;$i++){
$b = explode("=",$a[i]);
<!--exploded value will give $b[0] = hhjhj and $b[1] = 10 ok -->
$c[] = $b[1];
}

<!-- In $c array all the values came after =.....now -->
$k=0;
$l=6;
$h=0;
for($j=$k;$j<=$l;$j++){
if($j == $l){
$j = $k;
$l = $l + 5;
$h++;
}

<!-- So from this here we got no of set of rows to be inserted in table --it will give result [3] from array $c(mixed values of no of rows) -->

}

<!-- now going to split into rows  and insert-->

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){

$e=6;
for($j=0;$j<=$e;$j++){
if($j==$e){

$j=$e+1;
$e = $e+6;
break;
}else{
$row[$i] = $c[$j];
}
}


}

<!-- now we got --- -->
$row[1] = {0,date,date,ccsc,sslc,image};
$row[2] = {0,date,date,ccsc,sslc,image};
$row[3] = {0,date,date,ccsc,sslc,image};
```