# How to store found numbers inside a string into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Given a string:

```
$string = "Hello, 1992 world! Today's 2016! That's 24 years!";
```

How can I parse the string to return an array containing all the numbers inside?

Expected result:

```
{1992,2016,24}
```

Comment: try `preg_match_all()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `preg_match_all()` you can achieve what you want-

```
$str = "Hello, 1992 world! Today's 2016! That's 24 years!";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/d8F18)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Hello, 1992 world! Today's 2016! That's 24 years!";
preg_match_all("!\d+!", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```