# Getting numbers only from an array

Tags: php

i have this array in php

```
$name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
```

i wanted to strip all alphabets and dots in the string remains only number like

```
$name = array("18","16","17","19");
```

how do i achieve that can some one please guide me how to do it in PHP language

Comment: Have a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simplified and native solution from the house of PHP:

```
    $name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
    foreach ($name as $n) {
        $num_arr[] = filter_var($n, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    }

    var_dump($num_arr);
    exit();
```

Outputs:
Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 16 [2] => 17 [3] => 19 )

enjoy fresh air ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,use **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**

```
$name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
foreach($name as $val)
{
    $new_name[] = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $val);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/XtCaj)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using Regex by using string replace function ([`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)):

```
<?php
$name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
$myArra = array();
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
  $var = str_replace("page", "", $value);
  $var = str_replace(".jpg", "", $var);
  $myArra[] = $var; // store all value without text and .jpg
}
print_r($myArra);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 19
)
```

Or, if you want to use [Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), than you can use `/\d+/` pattern as like:

```
<?php
$name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
$myArra = array();
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
  preg_match_all('/\d+/', $value, $matches);
  $myArra[] = $matches[0][0];  // store all value without text and .jpg
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArra);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 19
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()`, you can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`filter_val()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) like so:

```
$name = array("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg",);
$name = array_map(function($fv) {
    return filter_var($fv, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    }, $name);

print_r($name);
```

> **Output:**
>
> Array
>
> (
>
> [0] => 18
>
> [1] => 16
>
> [2] => 17
>
> [3] => 19
>
> )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$name = array ("page18.jpg","page16.jpg","page17.jpg","page19.jpg");

$myarray =array(); 

foreach($name as $key =>$value){

$page_replace= str_replace("page", "",$value); //replace page as a blank

$jpg_replace= str_replace(".jpg","",$page_replace); //replace jpg to blank

$myarray[] =$jpg_replace;//stroing without jpg and page getting resulut as key value pair

}
echo "<pre>";

print_r($myarray);

?>
```

Comment: Getting numbers only from an array

Comment: This is pretty much just a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889122/getting-numbers-only-from-an-array/39889196#39889196).