# Format after multiplying in php

Tags: php, format

I do not know how to format after multiplying.
Example:
0.012333 * 3.500
Always zero left would be a fee.
Is there a way to format this 0.012333 after multiplying?

Comment: How do you want it formatted? example, what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Is it possible to multiply like this?
0.012333 * 3.500
Do you see any results?

Comment: 0.012333*3.500=0.0431655... if you type `echo 0.012333*3.5000;` php will calculate it, and print out 0.0431655. is that what you're trying to achieve? I have a difficulty understanding your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain.
I have this number 0.012332 when I make 0.012333 * $ 3,500.00 = 0

$ValueTotal = $listar3->date["house"] * $rate1->date["rateTaxa"];

Is it correct and format 0,012332 to give a whole number?

Comment: @Stefanato  You are **multiplying a String by a Float**. ***The result would thus be 0***  `$ 3,500.00` seem like a String. Most likely, you need to convert that  `$ 3,500.00` to either a `Float`, a `Double` or any `Number` Data-Type. Once that is done, your multiplication should work without throwing unexpected results at you. ***Just keep in mind that in PHP multiplying a Numeric value by a String always returns 0!***

Comment: As @Poiz notes... you will have to convert the string to a number. see the answers to this question, on how to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As someone rightly noted in the comments section of your Post, the result of multiplying `0.012333` by `3.500` would be `0.0431655`. However, if by **Format** You want to mean Formatting the Result (`0.0431655`) to some friendly-looking Figures, then you may want to consider working with PHP's `number_format()` Function which will return a String, given a `Floating Point Number` like `0.0431655`. The Snippet below demonstrates this:

```
<?php

    $result     = 0.012333 * 3.500;
    $formatted  = number_format($result, 2, '.', ',');

    var_dump($result);        //<== YIELDS:: float 0.0431655 
    var_dump($formatted);     //<== YIELDS:: string '0.04' (length=4)
```