# How to get specific substring digit from string using php?

Tags: php, string, substring, digit

```
$fileName = "Backup_1486874341.tar.gz"
```

Here is my file name. How can i get only timestamp from that file name Like `1486874341`

Comment: [extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: Try adding a little more description.

Comment: Have you tried solving this on your own?

Comment: Use `preg_match("/_(\d+)./", $str, $matches)`

Answer (score 0):

Use simple regex in [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to select target digit in file name.

```
$fileName = "Backup_1486874341.tar.gz";
preg_match("/_(\d+)./", $fileName, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/ucWOP)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample snippet:

```
<?php

$str = 'Backup_1486874341.tar.gz';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);

?>
```