# Extract number from html string

Tags: php

I have string contain numbers. I only want to get numbers. please help. Thank guys.

```
<?php
$a = '<td>15</td>';
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `strip_tags`

```
<?php
$a = '<td>15</td>';
echo strip_tags($a);
```

Comment: Thank you alot . you r so awesome my friend hehehe

Comment: Great..! Happy Coding...!

Answer (score 1):

```
$int = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: i got it . Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` will help you. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$a = '<td>15</td>';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $a, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: it prints an array() . i only need to get simple number . anyway thank Virb so much . Nice day my friend.

Comment: Happy to help. You can get answer as per Shubham and Nishant.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `strip_tags` is the good way.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php
$a = '<td>15</td>';
$number = strip_tags($a);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help.