# How to get numbers between html tags

Tags: php, regex

I want to get some numbers between html tags. I get everything between the html tags but I just need the numbers. I want to store them as integer in database.

Example HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 product-c"><span title="how many x product left"> 4 left</div>

$pattern = <div class="col-md-3 product-c"><span (?:.*?)>(.*?)</div>
```

This pattern gives me `4 left` but I want to get just the `4` (or what else) number, so I tried that below example:

```
$pattern = <div class="col-md-3 product-c"><span (?:.*?)>([0-9]+)</div>
```

But this time, it returns nothing, just an empty array.

How can I get only numbers between these tags?

Comment: Did you try doing this? It might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: @Parth Yes, I tried but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Parth That would be too loose for this. Something like `<h1>` would be matched.

Comment: @user3783243 Okay

Comment: Using an html parser library would help you a lot. Think about it if this is something you need to do extensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- You have whitespace before the digit(s) which you haven't accounted for
- You have text and spaces after the digit(s) which you haven't accounted for

It depends on which **exact** conditions you want to specify, but this will work:

```
<div class="col-md-3 product-c"><span (?:.*?)>(?:\s*)([0-9]+)(?:[^0-9]*)<\/div>
```

- `(?:.*?)` ignores anything that may be in the `<span>` attributes
- `(?:\s*)` ignores whitespace before the digit(s)
- `([0-9]+)` groups the digit(s) themselves
- `(?:[^0-9]*)` ignores anything after the digits

And this can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/J1Fmdk/1/)**.

Having said that, you may wish to consider an HTML parser.

Comment: it works, thank you for explaining in detail. I'm trying to learn but I'm so beginner in regular expressions..

Answer (score 1):

I think using a parser would be the best approach for this. Once you have the correct value (by parsing into the `span` and checking the `title`) you can just cast it to an int and it will be the value want.

```
$html = '<div class="col-md-3 product-c"><span title="how many x product left"> 4 left</div>';
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$spans = $dom->getelementsbytagname('span');
foreach($spans as $span) {
    if($span->getattribute('title') == 'how many x product left') {
        echo (int)$span->nodeValue;
    }
}
```