# How to find numbers in HTML?

Tags: php, regex

I should have mentioned that I use preg_match. 
It is a fix for a larger code, and switching method now will be a big headache.

I am trying to create a regex matching :

```
<span class="paper-name">some string</span>\r    </h1>\r    <div class="data-row">\r        <span class="num">0.25
```

What I really need is that last part - the number.
it can be from 0.00 to 9.99.

I tried to break it to:

```
<span class="paper-name">some string</span>
<div class="data-row">
<span class="num">
0.25
```

And find all in between No luck. Can someone please help?

I so so close: 
I can find the first part:

```
^.*(?<=(<span class="paper-name">some string<))
```

And the second part :

```
<))(?.*)(span\sclass\=\"num"\>(\d*\.\d*))
```

But i am not able to connect them. 
I need the first appearance after the first part of the second part.

Comment: Try this reg exp ```/[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/g```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parser way instead:

```
<?php

# html string
$html = <<<DATA
<h1>
    <span class="paper-name">some string</span>
</h1>
<div class="data-row">
    <span class="num">0.25</span>
</div>
DATA;

# set up the domdocument
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

# the xpath object
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

# query the dom
$numbers = $xpath->query("//span[@class = 'num']");

# iterate over the results
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->nodeValue;
}
```

This correctly yields

```
0.25
```

and will work for most other `HTML` snippets as well whereas a regular expression might not.

---

**Edit:**

If you insist on using regular expressions (why?), you might try:

```
<span class="num">\K\d(?:\.\d{2})?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/I9rbYN/2/).

Answer (score 0):

If you using regular expressions then try https://regex101.com/r/DGbVbp/1/:

```
$html = '<h1>
    <span class="paper-name">some string</span>
</h1>
<div class="data-row">
    <span class="num">


0.25

</span>
<div class="data-row">
    <span class="num">


0.22

</span>
</div>';

preg_match_all('#<span class="num">(?:\s+)?(?P<num>\d(?:\.\d{2}):?)#isu', $html, $match);
var_dump($match['num']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regex.

```
$str = '<span class="paper-name">some string</span><div class="data-row"><span class="num">0.25';

preg_match('/([0-9]+\.?[0-9].)/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Number must be between `0.00` and  `9.99` your regex matches `1.2X`and matches numbers inside `abcd123456.123456xyz`