# How to Filter Out two number in a string input on html

Tags: php

I want to get the two numbers in a string

Example: the user input "what is 177 x 55", then I want to get 177 and 55

```
$number1 = 177;
$number2 = 55;
```

Comment: What if the string is `calculate 155 x 55 + 4`? What numbers then?

Comment: Maybe a regex? What have you tried? What are example strings? Possibly `(\d+)\h+x\h+(\d+)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: I want to save first number to $number1 and second number to $number2

Comment: <?php



$mixed_input =  "what is 155 x 77";
$only_numbers = filter_var($mixed_input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $only_numbers;
//result is 15577
//but i want to seperate 15577 into two number which is 155 and 77
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this.

Regex will match and capture in strings according to a pattern, in this case the pattern is a simple any size digit.

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $string, $matches);
list($number1, $number2) = $matches[1];
```

The regex will capture any number of numbers in the string ("155 x 25 x 40" for example), but the list() function is the limiting factor here.
If there is three numbers in the list() will fail.
So I recommend you to use the array instead of the `list($number1, $number2)`.

https://3v4l.org/DcAsX

Comment: This answer solve my problem.
your example separate my two int in my string, thank you.

Comment: @ClarkDave no problem. Feel free to accept the answer