# Extract decimal number and character (usage units) of a data usage string in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, php-7.0

I have a string which returns data usage in B, KB, MB and so on. I want to separate the number and string part of it.

Ex : 14.5 MB - I want 14.5 and MB separately.

I tried using regex

```
'/(\d+)(\w)/'
```

but does not give the desired result.

Expected result

```
Array( [0] => 14.5, [1] => 'MB' )
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: This solution was not helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of explode function if you are sure that your string will always contains space in between

```
$consumedData = '14.5 MB';
$withSeperate = explode(' ',$consumedData);
var_dump($withSeperate);
```

Output

```
Array([0] => 14.5, [1] => 'MB');
```

Comment: What will happen if there is no space between the number and string!

Comment: it will give you an array with count 1 and your string is on index 0

Answer (score 2):

You may try using `preg_match_all` here with the following regex pattern:

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([KMGT]?B)\b
```

This matches a (possibly) decimal size, followed by a unit based in bytes.

```
$input = "Here are three sizes 14.5 MB, 10B, and 30.8 GB";
preg_match_all("/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([KMGT]?B)\b/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14.5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 30.8
)
Array
(
    [0] => MB
    [1] => B
    [2] => GB
)
```