# How to remove values using a blacklist array, then reduce the remaining values to eliminate gaps?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This question is basically an extension of my previous question:

[How to subtract value of array but still in position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812232/how-to-subtract-value-of-array-but-still-in-position/)

I have an input array of arrays.  The values in each subarray always consist of values starting from `0` and without any gaps, values are incremented by one.  However, the values are not necessarily in order AND I need to preserve this order while executing my required logic.

Next I have a blacklist of values that I wish to remove from all subarrays.  Any original subarray value that exists in the blacklist array must be removed.

Sample input array of arrays:

```
$arrays = [
    [0, 3, 10, 5, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 4, 8, 11],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 3, 2]
];
```

Sample blacklist array:

```
$deletes = [3, 5];
```

My desired output is:

```
[
    [0, 8, 4, 7, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 9],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
]
```

All remaining values greater than `3` are reduced by `1` and values greater than `5` are reduced by `2` since I deleted `2` numbers.

If all numbers in a given subarray are less than all of the numbers in the blacklist array, then no change is required for that subarray.

I have a coding attempt here https://3v4l.org/lX2MP, but I am stuck when returning their values. All array values were combining.

Comment: Thank you for your response @KurtFriars.. The **$deletes** variable is the example input, and the output is from database.

Comment: If this was a "function ($input, $deletes) { ... return $output; }" What is $input, $deletes, and its corresponding $output.

Comment: _“and the output is from database”_ - do _we_ have your database …? Show a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. In this case, that would mean that you also show example data for $range in code form, `$ranks = […];` Even if this relates to a previous question, please always make questions here self-contained.

Comment: This won't run on that server it needs to be copied in laravel and then you can try it out @Marky https://3v4l.org/CdDG2

Comment: I just only use a static array of data.

Comment: Yes but how come only the 2nd subArray is wrong on output and rest it was all correct? @mickmackusa

Comment: @KurtFriars I had prior knowledge because I answered the previous question.  I have edited the question to be more clear and improved the mcve.  If you find the question to be sufficiently clear and you either DV'ed or V'edTC, please consider undoing your votes.  If anything is still unclear, please say so.

Comment: @CBroe I had prior knowledge because I answered the previous question.  I have edited the question to be more clear and improved the mcve.  If you find the question to be sufficiently clear and you either DV'ed or V'edTC, please consider undoing your votes.  If anything is still unclear, please say so.

Comment: @NicoHaase I had prior knowledge because I answered the previous question.  I have edited the question to be more clear and improved the mcve.  If you find the question to be sufficiently clear and you either DV'ed or V'edTC, please consider undoing your votes.  If anything is still unclear, please say so.

Comment: @lewis4u please never post solutions as comments.  Your advice is not dynamic.  You are hardcoding the 3 and the 5 into the condition block.  This is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to alter your 2nd, 3rd and 4th subarrays slightly to better demonstrate the behavior.

Drawing upon one of the techniques in my answer to your previous question, I am effectively only just wrapping the code logic in an additional loop `array_map()`.

`array_diff()` is used to instantly destroy any values in the input array that match the deletes values.  Then `array_reduce()` is use on the remaining values of the input array to iterate and reduce the integers any generated eliminate gaps.

Inside of `array_reduce()`, you will see `$value > $item`. This comparison will return `true` or `false`.  When a boolean value is used as a number, `true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`.  Basically, I am either subtracting `0` or `1` from `$value` depending on how each `$deletes` value compares to the given `$value`.

As a specific example, when processing `10`, `10` is larger than `3`, so it becomes `9`, and `10` is larger than `5` so `9` becomes `8`.

This is all done without needing to pre-sort the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EmKUO))

```
$arrays = [[0, 3, 10, 5, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 4, 8, 11], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1], [0, 1, 3, 2]];
$deletes = [3, 5];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($array) use ($deletes) {
            $result = [];
            foreach (array_diff($array, $deletes) as $value) {
                $result[] = array_reduce(
                    $deletes,
                    function ($carry, $item) use ($value) {
                        return $carry - ($value > $item);
                    },
                    $value
                );
            }
            return $result;
        },
        $arrays
    )
);
```

Here's an alternative that behaves the same way but doesn't rely on functional programming so much: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aUc9d))

```
foreach ($arrays as $index => $array) {
    $filtered = array_diff($array, $deletes);  // destroy blacked values
    foreach ($filtered as $value) {
        $originalValue = $value;
        foreach ($deletes as $delete) {
            $value -= $originalValue > $delete; // reduce to eliminate gaps
        }
        $result[$index][] = $value;
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output (for either snippet):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 8,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 7,
    4 => 2,
    5 => 5,
    6 => 1,
    7 => 3,
    8 => 6,
    9 => 9,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete numbers from array and to subtract a count from the current number in the original array with the number of numbers smaller than it in `selectedDeletedNumbers`, you can:

- Sort the `selectedDeletedNumbers` array.
- Iterate over the original array and use [`binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to get the count of numbers smaller than the current number in the original array and subtract it later.
- If current number is present in `selectedDeletedNumbers`, then unset them.
- Apply the above operation on each individual subarray.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function subtract(&$arr,$selectedDeletedNumbers){ // pass by reference to edit the same copy of the array
    foreach($arr as $index => $val){
        $low = 0;$high = count($selectedDeletedNumbers) - 1;
        $equal_found = false;
        while($low <= $high){
            $mid = intval(($low + $high) / 2);
            if($selectedDeletedNumbers[$mid] > $val){
                $high = $mid - 1;
            }else if($selectedDeletedNumbers[$mid] < $val){
                $low = $mid + 1;
            }else{
                $equal_found = true;
                unset($arr[$index]); // if equal value, delete it as it your need
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if(!$equal_found){
            $arr[$index] -= $low; // delete the offset till where it is greater among your $selectedDeletedNumbers
        }
    }
}

$selectedDeletedNumbers = [3,5];
sort($selectedDeletedNumbers); // sort to be apply binary search later
$arr = [[0, 3, 10, 5, 6, 9, 2, 7, 1, 4, 8, 11], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]];

foreach($arr as &$val){ // pass by reference to edit the same copy of the array
    subtract($val,$selectedDeletedNumbers); 
}

print_r($arr);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/RMh5U

If you want to re-index the numbers sequentially, do an `array_values()` on each individual subarray in the end.