# Save filtered billing phone to admin user profile in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

Everything I have read over the last couple of days has indicated that if I want to save fields in the user-edit.php (User Admin Backend), I should be using the `edit_user_profile_update` & `personal_options_update` hooks (and I'm not including the validation hook in this question...)

**In the codex, they state that:**

> Consider an example:
>
> ```
> update_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_meta_key', $_POST['custom_meta_key']);
> ```
>
> Make doubly sure that you give a different key name for the `$_POST` data key and the actual user meta key. If you use the same key for both, Wordpress for some reason, empties the value posted under that key. 
> So you'll always get an empty value in `$_POST['custom_meta_key']` so change it in the html input element's name attribute and append a suffix. Changing it to `$_POST['custom_meta_key_data']` and it'll pass the data properly.

However, given the fact that I want to add validations to the existing `billing_phone` field, I do not know how to create said "`custom_meta_key_data`" (eg: `'_billing_phone'`, or `'prefix_billing_phone'`) to then enter the value into said prefix_billing_phone to then convert to `'billing_phone'` via `update_user_meta()`.

I have provided my base code below, and I have searched the internet for two days as to a solution, but I cannot find a workaround.

In addition, the `str_replace()` doesn't action, which made me look inside the `user-edit.php` and the comments support the quoted notes above, where between hitting update, and the profile reloading, it saves each variable as `_billing_` (prefixed '_') and records the original value (pre if statements / my code below) and saves that - not what I have conditioned/attempted to validate. I don't know how to copy that so that I can simply validate my fields...

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'audp_save_user_account_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'audp_save_user_account_fields' ); 

function audp_save_user_account_fields( $user_id ) {
    
    /* Input Value: "0412 345 678"
     * SHOULD Become: "0412345678"
     */
    $billing_phone = str_replace( array( ' ', '(', ')' ), '', $_POST['billing_phone'] );
    
    if ( !empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && preg_match( '/^04[0-9]{8}$/D', $billing_phone ) ) {
        
        $billing_phone_query = get_users( array( 
            'meta_key' => 'billing_phone',
            'meta_value' => $billing_phone, 
        ) );
        
        foreach ( $billing_phone_query as $query ) {
            
            if ( $user_id == $query->ID ) {
                
                /* This value ($billing_phone) should be eg: "0412345678"
                 * but remains "0412 345 678" 
                 */
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone );
            
            }
        
        }
    
    }

}
```

---

**Addition / Edit**

Under `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` the fields still do not update as per the conditionals. For example, if I enter '0411 111 111' (spaces), the spaces are not removed. I have attempted to do `var_dump( $_POST ); die();` at every stage of the conditional below and the value ('billing_phone') passes the changes (eg: 0411111111), but at the `update_user_meta()` and when the page reloads it reverts back to the '0411 111 111'? The code I have is:

```
function audp_save_user_account_fields( $user_id ) {
    
    $billing_phone_key = 'billing_phone';
    
    if ( isset( $_POST[$billing_phone_key] ) ) {
        
        // var_dump( $_POST['billing_phone_key] ) = '0411 111 111'
        $billing_phone = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/i', '', sanitize_text_field($_POST[$billing_phone_key] ) );
        // var_dump on $billing_phone = '0411111111'
        
        if ( !empty( $_POST[$billing_phone_key] ) ) {
            
            // var_dump( $billing_phone ) = '0411111111'
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone );
            // page reloads with value '0411 111 111'.
        }
        
    }

}
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'audp_save_user_account_fields' );
```

I read somewhere that you might have to pass the old variable and the new variable somehow and/or delete the user_meta_data and then add the new one but I have not tried that yet...?? Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

> Now to filter a phone number string keeping only numbers, you can better use `preg_replace()` than `str_replace()`.

In the following, The billing phone number will be filtered before saving in:

- Wordpress admin user dashboard
- My Account Addresses Edit billing Address
- Once order is placed (before data is saved)

The code:

```
// In Wordpress user profile (increased hook priority)
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_billing_phone_fields', 999999 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_billing_phone_fields', 999999 );
function save_user_billing_phone_fields( $user_id ) {
    $field_key = 'billing_phone';

    if( isset($_POST[$field_key]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        // Filtering billing phone (removing everything else than numbers)
        $billing_phone = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field_key]) );

        // Update the billing phone
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone );
    }
}

// On My account > edit addresses > Billing
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_myaccount_field_billing_phone', 'filter_my_account_billing_phone_fields' );
function filter_my_account_billing_phone_fields( $value ) {
    return preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $value );
}

// On order submission
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'wc_checkout_posted_data_filter_callback' );
function  wc_checkout_posted_data_filter_callback( $data ) {
    $field_key = 'billing_phone';

    if( isset($data[$field_key]) ) {
        // Filtering billing phone (removing everything else than numbers)
        $data[$field_key] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $data[$field_key] );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string/14789267#14789267)

Comment: Thank-you for your edit and inputs @LoicTheAztec. I appreciate the information re `preg_replace`. I have updated my question for a more detailed response to the issues I'm still faced with.

Comment: Thank-you again. I am away from my desk until tomorrow, but will test the changes to priority and the inclusion of `(int)` and reply accordingly.

Comment: My code is on the localhost at the office, as stated I can test it fully first thing tomorrow morning, and of course if it works I will gladly mark it as answered. Thank you for your time and experience once again.

Comment: @Aliqua Which redirect (I don't catch)? I remember you that your initial question was not related to field validation process… In StackOverFlow the rule is one question at the time, so you could please ask a new question with clear explanations and details, providing your code attempt. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it was a lapse in my thoughts. I'm aware of the rules and will ask a new question if required. Thank you again for your assistance. You're a valuable resource to StackOverflow.